# angularjs component: Initialize variables in $onInit before template is loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components

In angualarjs is there a way to initialize a variable in a component before the template is loaded from "templateUrl:".

Comment: That could help -> [OnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit#ngoninit)

Comment: I could but it is bad coding practice to use it